# Returning combined Observable only if a condition matches

Tags: android, operators, rx-java

Consider the following set and object:

```
Observable.from(users); // Where users = List<User> and each user has a userId
Observable.just(location); // Where location has id, userId, coordinates
```

What I would like to do is iterate over the list of users, and upon the first encounter where `location.userId.equals(user.userId);` is queried in a database, return a combined object. If `userId`s do not match move to the next user. And terminate the loop once 1 match is found.

How can I achieve this with RxJava?

I initially thought to use:

```
Observable.zip(Observable.from(users), Observable.just(location), new Func2<User, Location, UserLocation>() { ... });`
```

Does anyone have a better alternative?

#### Edit:

I thought maybe I could solve this with a simple solution, but alright I'll explain everything more clearly.

So once I have `location.userId`, and `user.userId` I need to also query a database which will return an `Observable<Boolean>` indicating whether it is also true in our database. If that condition matches then I return a combined object.

So the entire flow looks like this:

```
for each user in Users {
    checkIfAlreadyExistsInDatabase(user.userId, location.userId) // Returns Observable<Boolean>

    // If exists in db AND user.userId == location.userId return combined object and terminate the loop
}
```

This was previously being done synchronously without `RxJava` I converted the method `checkIfAlreadyExistsInDatabase` to Rx and use `Schedulers.io` to ping the database on a background thread to make the app more response. The issue came up when I had to iterate over an array of Users and match the id with Location AND also ping my database.

In order for me to call the method `checkIfAlreadyExistsInDatabase` I need to grab a `user.userId` and to do that I need to iterate over `users` and filter with `location.userId`.

So:

1. Iterate over users
2. If user.userId matches location.userId check if it exists in database
3. If exists in database return a combined object
4. Terminate loop once 1 match is found

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `zip` function is that it emits one item from left `Observable` and one item from right `Observable`. So the function you provided will execute only for the first user. But this is a good direction. Just repeat the second `Observable` appropriate amount of times - use `repeat`. If you really want to do this using RxJava, here is the suggested approach:

```
Observable.zip(Observable.from(userList),
        Observable.just(location).repeat(userList.size()),
        new Func2<User, Location, User>() {
            @Override
            public User call(User user, Location location) {
                return user.id.equals(location.id) ? user : null;
            }
        })
        .filter(new Func1<User, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(User user) {
                return user != null;
            }
        });
```

However with this approach `null` is passed through `Observable` stream and this is not recommended.

I wouldn't do it with RxJava, just with traditional Java's `Iterator`.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Almost. `take(1)` wil take the first user, either true user or null. Filter the results first, by checking if user is not null.

Comment: Cool, I condensed my code to use lambdas. Nice catch +1

Answer (score 2):

It's not just `Observable.just(location)`, right? If it's already known, then it's trivial. Assuming that it's also procured asynchronously, then the 2-parameter form of `flatMap` is your friend:

```
Observable
.just(location)
.flatMap(loc -> Observable
    .from(users)
    .filter(user -> user.userId == location.userId)
    .flatMap(user -> checkIfAlreadyExistsInDatabase(user.userId, loc.userId)
                     .filter(value->value),
             (user, value) -> user)
    .take(1)
    .map(user -> combine(user, location)
)
.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: testing out new answer

Comment: Will add a sidenote, importing the Apache Commons library would increase my DEX count by 3500 methods. I believe Android has a utility Pair class though

Comment: Rewrote solution to not require Pair.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this seems to be a good way to do it (not tested thought, so beware):

```
location = getLocation();
Observable.from(users)
    .flatMap(user -> return mPresenterRx.userIdAlreadyInDatabase(location, user.userId) // This returns a Observable<Boolean>
        .flatMap(alreadyExists -> alreadyExists ? Observable.just(user) : null)) // Flatmap back to a user
    .filter(user -> return user != null)
    .take(1)
    .map(user -> return combine(location, user)) // Returns a UserLocation
    .subscribe(...);
```

Quite possibly if you wanted to keep doing operations on this you could then zip or combineLatest on this and another observable:

```
Observable<UserLocation> getUserLocationObservable() {

    location = getLocation();
    return Observable.from(users)
        .flatMap(user -> return mPresenterRx.userIdAlreadyInDatabase(location, user.userId)
            .flatMap(alreadyExists -> alreadyExists ? Observable.just(user) : null))
        .filter(user -> return user != null)
        .take(1)
        .map(user -> return combine(location, user)); // Returns a UserLocation
}

// Combine 
Observable<UserLocation> userLocationObs = getUserLocationObservable();
Observable<OtherModel> otherModelObs = getOtherModelObs();
Observable.zip(userLocationObs, otherModelObs, ...)
    .subscribe(...);
```

If anyone sees issues here please comment below.